# Vertical Text Scroll In Java

Tags: java, animation, user-interface

I am trying to create a movie credits style scrolling animation to add to the end of the game demo I have made. I was wondering if there is any way to do this using Java SE without any third party libraries. Any help is useful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible. If a Swing GUI, you can place the text in a JTextArea, place that in a JScrollPane without scrollbars, and simply scroll the JScrollPane. If not a Swing GUI, then you will want to give us more information.

Comment: @Taxes45 See [How to use scroll panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) for more details